# How to duplicate Use Default Value checkbox functionality?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin, adminform, product-edit

I want to set up on a product (admin editing form) whether or not an attribute should or should not be displayed on the product view page.
I was thinking of adding a checkbox (something like Use default value) next to each of the attributes.

Any ideas on how can I do that?

I'm opened for any other ideas for my problem, but it has to be administrable in product edit form.

Comment: Which type of attribute you are looking?

Comment: Hello, I'm not looking for a certain type of attribute. I want in the product edit form, near every attribute, to show a checkbox, to set up if the attribute should be displayed on frontend page or not.